# latex blank table of contents

Tags: latex, texmaker

1. why the contents table is blank

   i am using texmaker , as a result i get contents title and the rest of the page is blank what did i do wrong

   ```
    ...

    \documentclass[12pt , a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1.5 mm}}
    \pagenumbering{gobble} 


    \tableofcontents
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    ~
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{introduction}
    \end{document}

    ...
   ```

Comment: my class is \documentclass[12pt , a4paper]{report}

Comment: Please make a [mre] which we can actually compile

Comment: The code you now show works fine. Did you compile two times?